# How do you build a recursive Expression tree in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-expressions, hierarchyid

We are using [EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId) to represent a hierarchy in our data.

My goal is to return the descendants of an object with a particular path of indeterminate length, e.g. given a tree with the hierarchy one->two->three->four, the path one/two/three would return four

Knowing the length of the path, I can make a query like this:

```
var collections = await context.Collections.Where(c => c.CollectionHierarchyid.IsDescendantOf(
    context.Collections.FirstOrDefault(c1 => c1.FriendlyId == "three" &&
        context.Collections.Any(c2 => c2.CollectionHierarchyid == c1.CollectionHierarchyid.GetAncestor(1) && c2.FriendlyId == "two" &&
            context.Collections.Any(c3 => c3.CollectionHierarchyid == c2.CollectionHierarchyid.GetAncestor(1) && c3.FriendlyId == "one")
        )
    ).CollectionHierarchyid
)).ToListAsync();
```

But how would you go about this if the length of the path is unknown? I can't call a recursive function from the expression because it won't compile from Linq to Entity Sql.

I know the answer lies somewhere in using System.Linq.Expressions to build the expression, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved without dynamic expression tree generation, at least not directly, but using standard LINQ query operators.

Let say you have a hierarchical entity like this

```
public class Entity
{
    public HierarchyId Id { get; set; }
   // other properties...
}
```

Given a subquery returning the full set

```
IQueryable<Entity> fullSet = context.Set<Entity>();
```

and subquery defining some filtered subset containing the desired ancestors

```
IQueryable<Entity> ancestors = ...;
```

Now getting all direct and indirect descendants can easily be achieved with

```
IQueryable<Entity> descendants = fullSet
    .Where(d => ancestors.Any(a => d.Id.IsDescendantOf(a.Id));
```

So the question is how to build `ancestors` subquery dynamically.

Applying some filter to the full set and retrieving the direct ancestors filtered by another criteria can be done by using simple join operator

```
from p in fullSet.Where(condition1)
join c in fullSet.Where(condition2)
on p.Id equals c.Id.GetAncestor(1)
select c
```

Hence all you need is to apply that recursively, e.g. having

```
IEnumerable<TArg> args = ...;
```

representing the filtering criteria arguments ordered by level, then the query can be built as follows

```
var ancestors = args
    .Select(arg => fullSet.Where(e => Predicate(e, arg)))
    .Aggregate((prevSet, nextSet) =>
        from p in prevSet join c in nextSet on p.Id equals c.Id.GetAncestor(1) select c);
```

With that being said, applying it to your example:

```
IEnumerable<string> friendlyIds = new [] { "one", "two", "three" };

var fullSet = context.Collections.AsQueryable();

var ancestors = friendlyIds
    .Select(friendlyId => fullSet.Where(e => e.FriendlyId == friendlyId))
    .Aggregate((prevSet, nextSet) =>
        from p in prevSet join c in nextSet on p.CollectionHierarchyid equals c.CollectionHierarchyid.GetAncestor(1) select c);

var descendants = fullSet
    .Where(d => ancestors.Any(a => d.CollectionHierarchyid.IsDescendantOf(a.CollectionHierarchyid));
```

Comment: Thank you for this; I made a dynamic expression tree solution, but this is much better. 
If you could, please add a missing parentheses to close the Select method on your applied example:
`.Select(friendlyId => fullSet.Where(e => e.FriendlyId == friendlyId)`

I believe you can make a single character edit while I need change at least six.

Comment: Sure, here you go :-)